# Python Runtime Error Saving Decimal as Percentage Image File

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to use matplotlib to turn this decimal into a percentage and save it to a .png image file, but I keep getting runtime, divide by 0 errors:

```
the_score = .876776876786876767868
percentage = "{:.15%}".format(the_score)
plt.figure(figsize=(0, 0), dpi=100)
plt.text(0.6, 0.7, str(the_score), size=100,
         ha="center", va="center",
         bbox=dict(boxstyle="sawtooth",
                   ec=(0.2, 0.6, 0.4),
                   fc=(0.2, 0.6, 0.4),
                  )
        )
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('Numerical_Accuracy.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=10)
```

Comment: It's not an error but a warning due to matplotlib's internal for the formatting of figure, if this doesn't directly impact your expected output you could simply ignore it

Comment: and why do you set figsize to 0?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have `figsize=(0, 0)`. Changing it to a non-zero figure size should resolve the divide by zero errors you are encountering.